# what's the directory of external storage on nexus LG

Tags: android, android-external-storage

The following code snippet is trying to store a `Gesture` object.

```
private Gesture mGesture;
private GestureLibrary store;
store.addGesture("test", mGesture);
store.save();
```

I'm wondering where is `mGesture` stored?

Just followed by the above code, the author gives the following code:

```
final String path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "gestures").getAbsolutePath();
Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.save_success, path), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

So I guess the `mGesture` is stored in somewhere indicated by `path`.
But I don't know what's path. I've tried debugging. It gives me something like: "storage/emulated/0/gestures/". But I can't find this directory on my device.
By the way, my device is nexus 4

Answer (score 0):

Nexus devices don't have an SD slot.  They pretend that somewhere on the internal drive is an SD card.  But the exact path returned by the function does exist on your device, otherwise you couldn't make a file to it.

By the way, do not depend on that returned value being the same across devices.  It isn't.

Comment: for the method `save` of `GestureLibrary`, it seems that it doesn't specify "where" to save the target object. How does the method `save` know where to do the save.

Answer (score 0):

Yea agree with gabe and also this is just a suggestion but you could use if and else alongside mkdirs to check if the directory or folder exists and if it doesnt already exist it will create a new folder in the specified location.

Answer (score 0):

As Nexus 4 does not have an external SD, (same thing for Nexus 5, on which I am working now), its OS emulates an SD temporarily. Thus, calling `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns the following path: `tempDirPath:/storage/emulated/0/`, but it can be later accessed by you at `/storage/emulated/legacy`.

Try accessing it via `adb shell`, this `legacy` folder will store the content of the emulated external SD.